# Demonstration of limits of real functions of two variables

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=0$ using the limit definition is relatively easy, it will find that $\epsilon=\delta^2$, however it is difficult for me to apply the limit definition to demonstrate for example that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (3,-1)}(x^2+y^2-4x+2y)=-4$  or  $\lim_{(x,y)\to (-2,3)}(x^3y^2)=-72$. In some books I saw that use $0<\ |x-a|<\delta$ and $0<\ |y-b|<\delta$ instead of $0<\sqrt {(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta$ to demonstrate some limits. What is the reason for this equivalence?
Try to understand this fact by equivalence of metrics, but do not succeed.Thank you for the help

Comment: That's the reason: all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent, in particular the max norm and the Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R $, the distance used is
$d (x,y)=|x-y|=\sqrt {(x-y)^2}.$

in $\mathbb R^2$, we can define others distances like

$$d_1((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=$$
$$\sqrt {( x_1-y_1)^2+( x_2-y_2 ) ^2  }. $$
(Euclidian distance)

or

$$d_2=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$$

or

$$d_3=\max (|x_1-y_1|,|x_2-y_2|) .$$

these 3 distances are equivalent:
$(\alpha d_1\leq d_2\leq \beta d_1...) $

so we can choose one of them, the easiest.

in your book, they used the distance $d_3$.